# How should a component with mutable internal state initially derived from props be structured?

Tags: svelte

In Svelte I often want a component to take a prop that is used to create the initial state of the component. The internal state of the component is then changed by user input. Finally, the user clicks save or done and an event is dispatched to the parent component with the results of the change.

For example, in https://svelte.dev/repl/d15778cf0e074c3f80d9763d55c44e4d?version=3.57.0, I have a Selector component that accepts an array of items as a prop. It internally tracks which items are selected.

```
export let items = []
$: selection = new Array(items.length).fill(false)
```

This creates a selection array the same size as the items and fills it with false whenever items changes.

When the "Select All" button is clicked I fill the array with true and mark selection as having changed.

```
function selectAll() {
    selection.fill(true)
    selection = selection
}
```

However, select all doesn't work because the reactive assignment derived from items is triggered and resets the selection.

I have tried a reactive block instead of a reactive assignment and got the same results.

```
let selection
$: {
    selection = new Array(items.length).fill(false)
}
```

I've also tried using a non-reactive assignment, but obviously that fails to update when the prop changes.

```
let selection = new Array(items.length).fill(false)
```

This seems to be a general issue I run into when building edit components of various types (e.g. auto-formatting number fields). The initial state is reactively derived from props, but that reactive assignment stops internal mutations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment of `selection` to itself in

```
    function selectAll() {
        selection.fill(true)
        selection = selection
    }
```

seems indeed to trigger the reset to the initial value. When changing it to one line ([`.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill?retiredLocale=de) returns the modified array) it works as expected

```
    function selectAll() {
        selection = selection.fill(true)
    }
```

Since I find modifying the value of a reactive variable rather unintuitive I would go with this version

```
    export let items = []

    let selection

    $: unselectAll(items)

    function unselectAll(items) {
        selection = new Array(items.length).fill(false)
    }

    function selectAll() {
        selection = selection.fill(true)
    }

    function toggleSelection(i) {
        selection[i] = !selection[i]
    }
```

Comment: I've experimented with this and it does work. However, it appears that the change to `function selectAll()` is not the key factor. Instead it appears that the `$: unselectAll(items)` is the decisive factor. So from this I infer that the pattern is that the internal mutable state should not be a reactive variable set from props. Instead it must be set by a function called reactively from the props.